# $x_1^4+x^4_2-x_3^4+4x_1x_2x_3=5$ is smooth?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Is the set of solutions to $x_1^4+x^4_2-x_3^4+4x_1x_2x_3=5$ smooth near the point$ (1,1,1)$?Find the equation of its tangent at $(1,1,1)$.

Is it just enough to check that partials are continuous and differentiable?

Suppose $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=x_1^4+x^4_2-x_3^4+4x_1x_2x_3-5$

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}=4x_1^3+4x_2x_3$

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}=4x_2^3+4x_1x_3$

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_3}=-4x_3^3+4x_1x_2$

These partials are all continuous and differentiable, so $f$ is a $C^1$ function, so I think it means that the set of solutions to $f$ is smooth. Evaluating each of the partials at $(1,1,1)$ gives me $8,8$ and $0$ respectively, but I don't see how that tells me any info on smoothness.

In regards to finding the tangent, do I just have to calculate the jacobian $Df$?

$Df=\begin{pmatrix}
4x^3_1+4x_2x_3& 4x_2^3 + 4x_1x_3 & -4x^3+4x_1x_2
\end{pmatrix}$

Evaluating this Jacobian at $(1,1,1)$ gives $(8,8,0)$.

I'm not sure if I'm going about this the right way.

Comment: The set of solutions to $f(x,y):=xy=0$ is not smooth near $(0,0)$, even though $f\in C^1$. There is a certain "technical condition" in the implicit function theorem. This condition is violated in my example, but not in yours.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use the Implicit function theorem... 
It will give you directly differentiability and the Jacoby matrix at (1,1,1)

Comment: But doesn't $F_y$ have to be invertible? In my example, isn't $F_y=0$, so that would mean its not invertible? (where $DF=(F_x | F_y)$)